# Motor will only run properly with a meter inline, will only pulse without

Tags: motor, dc

I have a DC 12V 550 motor that will not run properly while on a power supply.  It will only pulse and not consistently run.  I figured my power supply wasn't supplying enough current.  It's a 12V 8A power supply, so I hooked up my meter to it inline to read the current draw, and wouldn't you know it ran perfectly.

To further complicate things, it will also run perfectly if wired directly to the motor from the power supply, but not through a 5.5mm jack.

If I use a 10A power supply, it runs ok through the jack just fine without the meter inline.  I have tried various 5.5 barrel jacks and all have the same result.  These jacks are rated at 10A DC so why will it run with the meter inline, and only pulse without?

I have a few of these to build and I have a drawer full of 8A power supplies that I would rather use than spend the bucks on all new 10A units.

Comment: What is a "550 motor"?

Comment: Are you sure it's a single phase motor? How many wires does it have?

Comment: hearth: it is a size of a DC motor, a DC motor that uses brushes, as Chris said, similar to an RC car or power drill.   Yes, it is a single phase motor.

Comment: A single phase motor is an AC motor.

Comment: _"size of a DC motor"_ Size has nothing to do with its type.

Answer (score 3):

A "550 motor" or originally Mabuchi RS-550 is a size/style of brushed "can" motor most widely known for its use in a traditional radio control car, or possibly re-purposed for an airplane.  Similar motors are found in some portable drills, other devices, etc.

These are fairly powerful motors, but operate on low voltage.  Windings vary by application but are always high current.  Those intended for an RC car are wound to draw *extreme* current when spinning, which means they'll draw even absurdly more when just starting up, or worse, stalled.  Most affordable power supplies cannot handle such a motor; these motors are meant for high power density rechargeable batteries.

Basically what is happening is a repeated cycle where the motor gets some power, but trips the over-current protection on your under-capable power supply.  Then after a bit the power supply protection circuit resets, the motor gets some more power, and trips the overload again.  And again and again.

Really your motors and your power supplies are fundamentally incompatible.   The best path would be to buy more suitable motors, or else rewind the motors with more turns of finer wire, making them a higher voltage, lower current design (this actually *was* done - but typically by hobbyists going the other way.  Of course today, no self respecting RC hobbyist bothers with a brushed anything...)

You could try something extremely kludgy like putting a very high wattage power resistor of a fraction of an ohm in series with the motor (essentially what your meter is...), but that's wasteful.

Possibly you could use a very high rate PWM speed control, and limit the duty cycle to reduce the current sufficiently.

But really at the end of the day, you have parts that just aren't meant to be used together.

Comment: yes, I understand about the overload kicking in. I guess my ultimate question is how come it runs perfecty fine when I put my meter inline with it on the positive lead?

Comment: As in the parenthetical above, your meter and its leads comprise a small value high wattage power resistor, assuming you put it on the high current scale.  This apparently produces just enough limit to the current to prevent the overload from tripping.   You could try to find a power resistor to do the same, but it's a bit kludgy and wasteful, you're likely right on the edge of failure.

Comment: oops, hit enter too soon LOL.....    it also runs ok when i do not have it hooked up to these barrel jacks, but if i hook it up directly, it runs just fine....   the barrel jacks are rated to 10A DC.   I guess i'm just really puzzled as to why it runs fine with the meter....
   I do also understand about starting current being much higher than the no load current, whil eits running it is pulling barely an amp, but with a strong load it will go up to 4amp....    What is the meter providing to get it running initially?   the 10A supply works perfectly on these motors.

Comment: they are new geared 550 motors, yes similar to RC cars/planes/and hand drills... they are brushed motors as well, yes.oh and thank you for providing feedback and input :-)

Comment: ahh, gotcha...  and the other connector tht i'm using to "directly" connect might be adding just enough resistance as well...  as it is a connector that goes from barrel plug to wires, and I'm connecting the wires directly to the motor...   the actual barrel jack may not have as much resistance to to limit the flow...   gotcha.... I'll wind up switching to th a10A supplies, as they do work nicely at least for this effort... in the end I'll switch motors to be more compatable...

Comment: chris, I may not hae a choice but to add h epower resistor inline....what specs would you recommend ?

Comment: I really *wouldn't recommend*.  Theoretically though one which wouldn't get too hot with the motor in stall condition.  Once you have the current and the power resistor resistance you can calculate the wattage of dissipation in the resistor.